# Make flashing effect in Java paint

Tags: java, swing

I'm building snake game.

I want to make the screen in the background flashing when the game is over.

Any ideas how to make it ?

This is my code about the paint:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D snakePaint = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D applePaint = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D scorePaint = (Graphics2D) g;
    Graphics2D gameOverPaint = (Graphics2D) g;
    paintSnake(snakePaint);
    paintApple(applePaint);
    paintScore(scorePaint);
    if(gameOver){
        paintGameOver(gameOverPaint);
    }
}

private void paintScore(Graphics2D scorePaint){
    scorePaint.setPaint(Color.darkGray);
    scorePaint.setFont(new Font("Dubai Medium", Font.PLAIN, 25));
    scorePaint.drawString("Score: " + apple.getScore(), 25, 25);
}

private void paintApple(Graphics2D applePaint){
    applePaint.setPaint(Color.red);
    applePaint.fillOval(apple.getxPos(), apple.getyPos(), SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_SIZE);

}

private void paintSnake(Graphics2D snakePaint){
    for(int i = 0; i<snakeList.getCount(); i++){
        snakePaint.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        snakePaint.fillRect(snakeList.getSnakeLinks()[i].getxPos(), snakeList.getSnakeLinks()[i].getyPos(),
                SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_SIZE);
        snakePaint.setPaint((Color.gray));
        snakePaint.drawRect(snakeList.getSnakeLinks()[i].getxPos(), snakeList.getSnakeLinks()[i].getyPos(),
                SNAKE_SIZE, SNAKE_SIZE);
    }
}

private void paintGameOver(Graphics2D gameOverPaint){
    gameOverPaint.setPaint(Color.red);
    gameOverPaint.setFont(new Font("High Tower Text", Font.PLAIN, 50));
    gameOverPaint.drawString("Game Over" , (PANEL_SIZE/2)-(gameOverPaint.getFontMetrics().stringWidth("Game Over") / 2),
            (PANEL_SIZE/2));

}
```

also got timer and actionListener to make the repaint if you need the code ill edit.

i want the gameover to stay regular but the snake, the score and the apple in the background to flash every sec or 2.

thx for the help :)

Comment: Off-topic: It's good that you selected a blink rate of 1 per 1 second or 1 per 2 seconds.  A while back, it was noticed that flashing a few to several times per second could trigger an epilepsy like response in some people.

Comment: 1) Are you aware that the first word of a sentence should start with a capital letter? 2) What is the point of casting the Graphics object 4 times. This does not create a new instance of the object. 3) Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` , not paint().

Comment: 4) The job of the paintComponent() method is to paint the current state of the game. So if you want to toggle the state of some object, then you need to property that you can change between true/false. Then in your Timer logic you change the state and invoke repaint on the components. The painting logic then checks this property before painting the object. Create a simple [mre] to demonstrate this concept. Just create a panel that paints something based on a property and use the Timer to toggle the property. Then if you have a problem you have complete code to paint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## introduction

I couldn't copy the posted code into my IDE, compile it, run it, and test it, so I created the following example GUI.

[image: Example]

Here's the GUi after 1.5 seconds.

[image: Horizotal]

Here's the GUi after 1.5 seconds.

[image: Vertical]

The squares will keep alternating every 1.5 seconds.

## Explanation

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

I created an application model consisting of 5 squares.  I created two plain Java getter/setter classes, `DrawingObject` and `BlinkingModel`

The `DrawingObject` class holds a `Rectangle`, a `Color`, and a `boolean` draw indicator.  This information is used by the drawing `JPanel` to draw the object.

The `BlinkingModel` class holds 5 `DrawingObject` instances and the `Dimension` of the drawing `JPanel`.

I created a `JFrame` and a drawing `JPanel`.  The `paintComponent` method of the drawing `JPanel` is pretty simple.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

The Swing `Timer` executes the `actionPerformed` method of the `ActionListener` every 1.5 seconds.  The `actionPerformed` method turns certain `DrawingObject` instances on or off (true or false) and repaints the drawing `JPanel`.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class BlinkingExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BlinkingExample());
    }
    
    private final BlinkingModel model;
    
    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    public BlinkingExample() {
        this.model = new BlinkingModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Blinking Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(1500, new ActionListener() {
            private boolean horizontal = true;
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                DrawingObject[] objects = model.getDrawingObjects();
                if (horizontal) {
                    objects[1].setDraw(false);
                    objects[2].setDraw(false);
                    objects[3].setDraw(true);
                    objects[4].setDraw(true);
                } else {
                    objects[1].setDraw(true);
                    objects[2].setDraw(true);
                    objects[3].setDraw(false);
                    objects[4].setDraw(false);
                }
                horizontal = !horizontal;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private final BlinkingModel model;

        public DrawingPanel(BlinkingModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setPreferredSize(model.getDrawingPanelSize());
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            for (DrawingObject object : model.getDrawingObjects()) {
                if (object.isDraw()) {
                    g.setColor(object.getColor());
                    Rectangle r = object.getDrawingObject();
                    g.fillRect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class BlinkingModel {
        
        private final Dimension drawingPanelSize;
        
        private final DrawingObject[] drawingObjects;
        
        public BlinkingModel() {
            this.drawingPanelSize = new Dimension(300, 180);
            this.drawingObjects = new DrawingObject[5];
            
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(140, 80, 20, 20);
            drawingObjects[0] = new DrawingObject(r, Color.BLUE);
            r = new Rectangle(140, 40, 20, 20);
            drawingObjects[1] = new DrawingObject(r, Color.BLUE);
            r = new Rectangle(140, 120, 20, 20);
            drawingObjects[2] = new DrawingObject(r, Color.BLUE);
            r = new Rectangle(100, 80, 20, 20);
            drawingObjects[3] = new DrawingObject(r, Color.BLUE);
            r = new Rectangle(180, 80, 20, 20);
            drawingObjects[4] = new DrawingObject(r, Color.BLUE);
        }

        public Dimension getDrawingPanelSize() {
            return drawingPanelSize;
        }

        public DrawingObject[] getDrawingObjects() {
            return drawingObjects;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class DrawingObject {
        
        private boolean draw;
        
        private final Color color;
        
        private final Rectangle drawingObject;

        public DrawingObject(Rectangle drawingObject, Color color) {
            this.drawingObject = drawingObject;
            this.color = color;
            this.draw = true;
        }

        public boolean isDraw() {
            return draw;
        }

        public void setDraw(boolean draw) {
            this.draw = draw;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }

        public Rectangle getDrawingObject() {
            return drawingObject;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Good answer, 1+, but warning that we've got a [help vampire here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76681287/522444).

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Maybe I'm missing something, but the OP has asked 11 questions in the last year.  Has he deleted a bunch of questions?